# Building UKUI Peony FIle manager from source

Tags: software-installation, github

Hi I'm trying to build peony-extensions from source github link here
https://github.com/ukui/peony-extensions

so I can build it to work with the latest git version of peony
However the instructions aren't clear to me so I was hoping I could get some help

Here's a snippet of their instructions

```
 

Create build directory and change to it, then build with cmake. The follow commands will auto build extensions as library.

cmake ..
make

    Put the generated libraries into &&[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]/peony-extensions.

    Test the extension with peony.
```

if someone could help with building this from source that would be appreciated as I can't figure it out cmake doesn't even work because in the non release version a file is missing

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 21.10 Daily build @N0rbert

Comment: 21.10 is currently off-topic here. But you can try by getting build dependencies for [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/impish/peony-extensions) by `sudo apt-get build-dep peony-extensions` and then proceed with cmake using git-sources.